# Mat-calendar hover color

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui, angular-material

I want to color the hover color of the Mat-calender element.

I have already succeeded doing so with this css:

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell-content:hover {
background-color:#something }
```

The problem is that if you hold the cursor in the corner of the cell the original color is still shown.

How can I reach the CSS and color it (on the image it is purple)?

[Mat-calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JfzY.png)

Comment: is there a reason you don't use the theme color for this ?

Comment: Yes, our site has another color we want to use. But I realise it would be easier to just make a custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

Using chrome dev tools and forcing the element state to `:hover` I was able to find the selector.

[image]

```css
.mat-calendar-body-cell:not(.mat-calendar-body-disabled):hover>.mat-calendar-body-cell-content:not(.mat-calendar-body-selected):not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
    background-color: #62bdfc;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b95tmy?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: OMG. Thankyou. I was doing the exact same but without finding that.